# Spring 3.2: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was upgrading to Spring 3.2.2, but getting following error.

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$889f2587 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

remove `<mvc:annotation-driven />` from spring-servlet.xml(or any other -servlet.xml) and restart server again.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more about why it needs to be removed?

Comment: @MauSánchez It most likely needs to be remove because you have specified `@EnableWebMvc` on some Java Config class

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue, Tomcat server was throwing same error when i upgraded from Spring 3.1.1 to 3.2.3 version. I solved the issue by removing  from **servlet-context.xml** file. This attribute is used to enable the Spring MVC @Controller via programming model.